# Numpy array filtering by two criteria

Tags: python, numpy, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm trying to run a custom kmeans clustering algorithm and am having trouble getting the document frequency for each column(term) of a 2-d numpy array by cluster.  My current algorithm has two numpy arrays, a raw dataset that lists the documents by terms [2000L,9500L] and one that is the clustering assignment [2000L,].  There are 5 clusters.  What I need to do is create an array that lists the document frequency for each cluster - basically a count in each column where the column number matches a row number in a different array.  The output will be a [5L, 9500L] array (clusters x terms).  I'm having trouble finding a way to do the equivalent of a countif and group by.  Here is some sample data and the output I would like if I ran it with only 2 clusters:

```
import numpy as np

dataset = np.array[[1,2,0,3,0],[0,2,0,0,3],[4,5,2,3,0],[0,0,2,3,0]]
clusters = np.array[0,1,1,0]
#run code here to get documentFrequency
print documentFrequency
>> [1,1,1,2,0],[1,2,1,1,1]
```

my thoughts would be to select out the specific rows that match each cluster, because then counting should be easy.  For example, if I could split the data into the following arrays:

```
cluster0 = np.array[[1,2,0,3,0],[0,0,2,3,0]]
cluster1 = np.array[[0,2,0,0,3],[4,5,2,3,0]]
```

Any direction or pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is any easy way to vectorize your code, but if you have only a few clusters you could do the obvious:

```
>>> cluster_count = np.max(clusters)+1
>>> doc_freq = np.zeros((cluster_count, dataset.shape[1]), dtype=dataset.dtype)
>>> for j in xrange(cluster_count):
...     doc_freq[j] = np.sum(dataset[clusters == j], axis=0)
... 
>>> doc_freq
array([[1, 2, 2, 6, 0],
       [4, 7, 2, 3, 3]])
```

Comment: @flyingmeatball This may be of interest to you. I have written a gufunc version of `np.bincount`, see [here](https://github.com/jaimefrio/new_gufuncs). If you can compile and install it (running `python setup.py install` should do the trick if your system is properly set up), you could then do something like `import new_gufuncs as ng; doc_freq = ng.bincount(clusters, dataset.T).T`, with all the looping happening in C.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jaime says, if you have only a few clusters it makes sense to use the usual trick of manually looping over the smallest axis length.  Often that gets you most of the benefits of full vectorization with a lot less of the headache that comes with being clever.

That said, when you find yourself wanting `groupby`, you're often in a domain in which a higher-level tool like [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) comes in very handy:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(dataset).groupby(clusters).sum()
   0  1  2  3  4
0  1  2  2  6  0
1  4  7  2  3  3
```

And you can easily fall back to an `ndarray` if needed:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(dataset).groupby(clusters).sum().values
array([[1, 2, 2, 6, 0],
       [4, 7, 2, 3, 3]])
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at Pandas - you're probably right, if it doesn't fit nicely it's best to try another approach.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how well compiled your BLAS is writing this as a matrix multiplication *could* be faster:

```
cvals = (clusters == np.arange(clusters.max()+1)[:,None]).astype(int)

cvals
array([[1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0]])

np.dot(cvals,dataset)
array([[1, 2, 2, 6, 0],
       [4, 7, 2, 3, 3]])
```

Lets create two definitions:

```
def loop(cvals,dataset):
     cluster_count = np.max(cvals)+1
     doc_freq = np.zeros((cluster_count, dataset.shape[1]), dtype=dataset.dtype)
     for j in xrange(cluster_count):
         doc_freq[j] = np.sum(dataset[cvals == j], axis=0)
     return doc_freq

def matrix_mult(clusters,dataset):
     cvals = (clusters == np.arange(clusters.max()+1)[:,None]).astype(dataset.dtype)
     return np.dot(cvals,dataset)
```

Now for some timings:

```
arr = np.random.random((2000,9500))
cluster = np.random.randint(0,5,(2000))

np.allclose(loop(cluster,arr),matrix_mult(cluster,arr))
True

%timeit loop(cluster,arr)
1 loops, best of 3: 263 ms per loop

%timeit matrix_mult(cluster,arr)
100 loops, best of 3: 14.1 ms per loop
```

Note this is with a threaded mkl BLAS. Your milage will vary.